# Copy and updating with Zend_Db

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db

I have 4 Tables. Customers, Templates, Elements and ElementsToTemplate. Quite self-explanatory. Customer can have n Templates. Templates can have n Elements. A Template can have 1 customer. A element can have 1 template.

So, now i need to make a delete and copy functionality for templates and customer.

What's the best approach for that?

Atm, i have a, actually not that ugly, monster function: http://pastebin.com/yBqKYnCC

I just think, my Design sucks a bit since i have for each one a Model/Object. Customer, Element and Template. Anyway, it isn't that ugly and I'm a newbie. This is stuff i didn't think of in the beginning.

Deleting. For deleting, as you probably noticed, I just set a flag and don't actually deleted anything. Is there some fancy way to update all in one query with Zend_Db_Select? Or do i have to go through all of them like i did for the copying?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Ok your heart is in the right place. :)
 Your function is kind of a monster, it should probably be broken down into 3 or 4 different functions.
 
To keep it simple and not reinvent the wheel I suggest you look at a couple of links to get the idea of the easier ways to use Zend_Db_Table.

The first is really good ZF primer that will lay the groundwork for using Zend_Db_Table:
[Rob Allen's ZF 1.11 Tutorial](http://akrabat.com/zend-framework-tutorial/)

The second one goes deeper into relationships:
[Mat M. Table Relationships in ZF](http://mattmccormick.ca/2010/04/24/how-to-easily-create-models-and-table-relationships-in-zend-framework/)

Comment: I also thought in splitting them, but then I'd have functions like getElements() in my customer class, this doesn't sound nice. That's what  I meant with my design sucks a bit.  He works with zf tool, i don't want to work with zf tool. Also i've done this tutorial already. Also a guy who worked on Zend_Db_Table said on stackoverflow my model should have a table/row but not be one.  It is just this Function which doesn't fit very well into the existing stuff. Hmm, I'll have to redesign my stuff a bit so i don't have elements related functions in my customer class. :) Thanks for the links.

Comment: you don't have to use zend_tool if you don't want to, it's just there for convenience. If you use DbTable models that extend Zend_Db_Table_Abstract most of the CRUD functions are available.